# c structures that contain function pointers

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I declare all my structures using the following macro..

```
#define structure                     typedef struct
```

with this I declare a structure , for example

```
structure
{
    int foo;
    int(*proc)(void*);
}
_myobject;
```

the member proc , really received the argument which is a pointer
to the structure it belongs to ..

e.g.

```
myobj.proc(&myobj);
```

My question is , how can I declare the member `proc` with the type being
passed to it as a structure , and not a `void *`  .. I know it doesn't make
a difference, this is only for aesthetics, as I have spent a lot of time 
keeping my code clean..

```
structure
{
    int foo
    int(*foo)(_myobject*);
}
_myobject;
```

produces:

```
error: expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '__attribute__' before 'int'|
```

Comment: You've declared `proc` to be a function pointer, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're attempting to refer to your struct recursively, which doesn't play nice with typedefs. One of the following should do:

```
typedef struct _myobject _myobject;
struct _myobject {
  int foo;
  int (*proc)(_myobject*);
};
```

...

```
typedef struct _myobject {
  int foo;
  int (*proc)(struct _myobject*);
} _myobject;
```

**edit:** If you want to continue using `structure` as much as possible (though really, other than for consistency with the existing code, I'm not sure why you would want to), you could do:

```
structure _myobject _myobject;
struct _myobject {
  int foo;
  int (*proc)(_myobject*);
};
```

...

```
structure _myobject {
  int foo;
  int (*proc)(struct _myobject*);
} _myobject;
```

Though both of these will require use of the `struct` identifier, if you wanted to avoid that.

Comment: problem is - the existing source ( >50k lines ), is full of structure -- I've done away with all struct identifer * , -

Comment: I tend to agree, there is no clean solution for this.. ok - I'll close the question - thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can change the macro a little:

```
#define structure(x,y)                     typedef struct x y x

structure (_myobject,
{
int foo;
int(*proc)(struct _myobject*);
}
);
```

which looks bad to me. Another way to do this is:

```
#define structure                     typedef struct

structure _myobject
{
int foo;
int(*proc)(struct _myobject*);
}
_myobject;
```